# How can I configure webpack 3.5.4 to only create source maps for JS, and skip CSS?

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I've been trying to figure out how to skip the CSS source maps in production, because I only need JS. Is there a way to do this?

I can just delete the `*.css.map` files later, but I think the build would be faster if I can skip them.

Comment: post your config file please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a snippet from my webpack config. You can simply set the value of `sourceMap` option to `false`:

```
 {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false,
                                importLoaders: 2,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
```

You can also use [suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/alxlu/suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin) to remove the `.css.map` files, because webpack still writes them even if they are empty.

Add a new plugin to your config:

```
// Skip empty CSS source maps
new SuppressChunksPlugin([     
  { name: 'your-entry', match: /\.css\.map$/ },
]),
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I ended up doing that. I was just getting a lot of warnings from the postcss-loader because I was using an older version (2.0.1), but they removed these warnings in a later version.

Comment: I accepted your answer and also wanted to add a note about the "SuppressChunksPlugin", which I'm using to remove the empty `.css.map` files